# Convert .STL file to NetworkX graph object?

Tags: python, 3d, networkx, graph-theory, numpy-stl

I was wondering if there was an easy way to convert a .STL file to a graph object. I've imported the STL file using numpy-stl and can return a vector representation of the mesh (a list of triangles) and this seems very similar to a graph object so I was wondering if there is a fast/efficient way to convert this to a NetworkX graph?

Comment: Did you find anything? I am looking to do the same.

Comment: I didn't but there are many useful python libraries that you could look into that could achieve what you're trying to do eg trimesh